# intelliSense: cant open source file "d3dx11.h"

Tags: directx-11

Visual Studio 2010 shows error on a DirectX program, which is taken from a books source code.I am very new to DirectX programming. There is not any Microsoft DirectX SDK folder in my computers programs files(i'm using win 8.1). When i try to reinstall DirectX setup has determined that a newer or equivalent version of DirectX has been installed already. I dont khow what is the matter please help me.

Comment: Note that all versions of D3DX including D3DX11 are [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). Consider using one of the many [replacement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx) solutions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use D3DX, you need to install the [June 2010 DirectX SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812).  This is the last SDK that supported D3DX.  [This page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx) also has some good info on what you need to write DirectX applications.

Comment: Note that you can use the Windows 8.1 standalone SDK with VS 2010 for Win32 desktop applications, but you'll need the .props files from my [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx). [DirectXTK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929), [DirectXTex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248926), [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx), and [DirectXMesh](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=324981) all support VS 2010 with the Windows 8.1 SDK.

Comment: And so does [Effects 11](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271568) and [DXUT](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320437). That said, I'm likely to drop support for VS 2010 whenever Visual Studio "14" ships, and you can always use the Express edition of VS 2012 or VS 2013 instead, so you may want to consider using one of those to [learn DirectX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/07/11/getting-started-with-direct3d-11.aspx) instead (see also [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/04/07/book-recommendations.aspx) for some notes on recent DX11 books).

Comment: There is now a new option: You can use the [Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX) NuGet package instead of the legacy DirectX SDK. That said, D3DX11 is still deprecated so you should still look at the various [replacements](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/).